# Rails 5.1 Validation of an object dependent on another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models Building and Listing. The Listing model belongs to Building. We have been trying to restrict the number of records that can be created in Listing depending on the number of active Listing records at a given time e.g. Listing.active.count can never be more than X. We tried to use a validation where if an integer column in Building were used as the limit, but it was not working and getting the following error,

```
undefined method `>=' for #<Array:0x007f05ec4db388>
```

**Listing.rb**

```
Class Listing < Application Record
  validates :validate_listing_count, on :create   

  private
    def validate_listing_count
      errors.add(:base, "You have too many active listings, please destroy a listing or contact your Account Manager if you need more listings") unless too_many_siblings?
    end

    def active_siblings
      building.listings.where(active: true)
    end

    def too_many_siblings?
      active_siblings.select { |sib| sib.id != id } >= (building.listing_limit - 1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`active_siblings.select` returns an array and you want the number of items in the array.  Try this:

```
def too_many_siblings?
  active_siblings.select { |sib| sib.id != id }.count >= (building.listing_limit - 1)
end
```

This was not part of the question, by you may want to change `unless` to `if` in `validate_listing_count`.  I think it makes more logical sense base on your description of the problem.

Comment: I tried that but we got the same error. My college thinks he may have been approaching this the wrong way

Comment: You may want to try again.  My code may not be correct, but it should not be generating that error.  Do you have a `>=` operator somewhere else in your code?  BTW, if you are using the Rails console for testing, you need to quit the console and reopen it any time you change your model to ensure the new model code is loaded.

Comment: ok so we saw your updated code and it is working but in the opposite way. It's not allowing me to update/create any new or existing records because its saying that we have too many active records at the moment,(listing limit im using for testing is 3 and we have one active record)

Comment: Yes.  You may want to change `unless` to `if`.